# PHP change date format of a field before returning JSON encode strings

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a php code where it fetches all the fields (about 50 of them) in a table name "account". The code works as intended. However, I need to change the date format of the field "register_date" from "Y-m-d H:i:s" to "m-d-Y" then returning JSON encoded strings. I can use the code below, but it becomes tedious since I have 50 fields.

```
$json_response = array();
$json_response['registered_date'] = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($result['registered_date']));
$json_response['contract_number'] = $result['contract_number'];
```

Is there a way to do it expediently?

```
$order = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['order_list']), ENT_QUOTES);
$id = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id_list']), ENT_QUOTES);
$sql = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE contract_number=:order AND id=:id");

$sql->bindValue(':order', $order, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json_response = array();
$json_response['registered_date'] = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($result['registered_date']));
$json_response['contract_number'] = $result['contract_number'];

die(json_encode($json_response));
```

Comment: You can return the date in the desired format straight from MySQL. Read about [date formatting in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). You should also read about the [date() function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Sometimes it's easier to ask, I know...

Comment: You're concatenating to the `$result`?  That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: 50 fields is a lot. I suppose you could make an array with the field names and them loop through that array each result. Watch out for timezones with ```date``` btw, as it will show your system's configured timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just change the PDO statement:

```
$sql = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE contract_number=:order AND id=:id");
```

to

```
$sql = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT *, date_format(register_date,'%m-%d-%Y') register_date FROM account WHERE contract_number=:order AND id=:id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date output from mysql but I don't really do that, this is how I do it in php.

1. Create a new DateTime object from the query
2. Get the desired format using the format() method and then replace the value in the query result with the new string

   $date_string = (new \DateTime($result->register_date))->format('m-d-Y');

   $result->register_date = $date_string;

   return $result;